# I need a way to count numbers in a string using basic code

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I don't understand the other code found on this website and would really appreciate the help.
By the way, I have no idea how to use this website and sincerely apologize If I'm formatting this question wrong. I should note that i need to add the number & vbtab & occurances. All this is to go in a lstbox.

```
 Private Sub btnCount_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs)         Handles btnCount.Click
    Dim NumberCounts As Integer
    Dim phrase As String
    phrase = Me.txtNumbers.Text

    Call CountNumbers(phrase, NumberCounts)
```

Could I modify this code for numbers?

```
  For character as integer = 0 to phrase.length -1
uppercaseLetter = char.ToUpper(phrase.lengthchars(character))
 if uppercaseLetter>= "A" and uppercaseLetter <= "Z" then
 letterIndex = Ascw(uppercaseLetter)
lettercounts(letterindex) +=1 
 end if
 next character
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't really tell us anything.  Post the code for `CountNumbers`.

Comment: @Tim this is my problem. I have no idea where to begin.

Comment: Google is your friend, Very first page from searching "vb.net count numbers in string"
http://www.worldbestlearningcenter.com/index_files/VB.NET-Char-counting-digits.htm

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is to count the number of digits ("0" - "9") in a phrase, you can make CountNumbers a function that takes a String as its argument and returns an Integer. For example:

```
Function CountNumbers(phrase As String) As Integer
    Return phrase.Count(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))
End Function
```

Or if you prefer:

```
Function CountNumbers(phrase As String) As Integer
    Dim numberCount As Integer 
    For Each ch As Char In phrase
        If Char.IsDigit(ch) Then numberCount += 1
    Next
    Return numberCount 
    Return phrase.Count(Function(c) Char.IsDigit(c))
End Function
```

Both versions use the Char.IsDigit method to test if each character in the String is a digit. You could use it to display the number of digits in the phrase entered in a TextBox like this:

```
Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = CountNumbers(TextBox1.Text).ToString 
End Sub
```